# Accounting for nulls the correct way

Tags: sql

In my below query I want to account for and not count users with null value in distance column - which of the below is the most optimal? I am also not sure how the HAVING ifnull works but it removes any user with null in distance column or 0 as the sum which what I wanted

Having

```
SELECT
name,
SUM(distance) as distance_traveled
FROM users
LEFT JOIN rides
ON users.id = rides.passenger_user_id
GROUP BY name
HAVING IFNULL(SUM(distance), 0)
```

Coalesce

```
SELECT
name,
COALESCE(SUM(distance),0) as distance_traveled
FROM users
LEFT JOIN rides
ON users.id = rides.passenger_user_id
GROUP BY name
```

Not Null Filter

```
SELECT
name,
SUM(distance) as distance_traveled
FROM users
LEFT JOIN rides
ON users.id = rides.passenger_user_id
and distance is not null 
GROUP BY name
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Please add sample data to make your question more clear.

Comment: Hi, I just want the output not to have any nulls

Comment: because some users have null in distance

Comment: Please add sample input and output data to your question, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SUM` aggregate function, by default, will ignore `NULL` values.  So, any names having a mixture of `NULL` and non `NULL` distances will only report the sum of the non `NULL` values.  However, for the case of a name *only* having `NULL` distances, the sum would return `NULL`.  Using `COALESCE` as you have done in the second version is a typical way of dealing with this:

```sql
SELECT u.name, COALESCE(SUM(r.distance), 0) AS distance_traveled
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN rides r
    ON u.id = r.passenger_user_id
GROUP BY u.name;
```

If you want to remove any users having all `NULL` distances, then add the following `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(r.distance) = 0
```

If you want to filter off any users with all zero distances (i.e. either missing *or* present but reported as `NULL`), then use this `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING SUM(r.distance) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, so what does the HAVING IFNULL(SUM(distance), 0) do ?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense, because you are comparing the value of `IFNULL` to some other value.  What followed `HAVING` should be some kind of boolean expression.

Comment: thanks, what does the   HAVING COUNT(r.distance) = 0 do? does it mean the distance of users has to equal 0?

Comment: @Chris90 The count = 0 asserts that there does _not_ exists even a single distance value which is non `NULL`.

Comment: sorry just want to make sure the having count = 0  asserts that there does NOT exist even one distance value that is not null? Prior you suggested it removes any users having all null?

Comment: I dont seem to understand how the having count() omits records with all nulls :/

Comment: The `COUNT` function counts `NULL` as zero.  So any group having only nulls would have a count of zero.

Comment: thanks so to filter off it would be =! and not = right?, as in your example above